# Typedef with multiple outputs

Tags: c++

I just found out that the following is valid C++

```
typedef const char* PSTR, *LPSTR;
```

my question is: are PSTR and LPSTR the same alias?

Why if I change it to

```
typedef const char* PSTR, LPSTR;
```

I get that LPSTR is a char??

Comment: It's exactly like a variable declaration, with a `typedef` in front.

Comment: And now that the answers below have explained it - probably better to forget the whole thing and stick to one identifier per typedef.

Comment: @GavinLock Sure, that is the most readable, but I think he saw this line in a MS Windows header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is why I always stick the `*` to the name and not to the type.

When you type

```
typedef const char *PSTR;
```

you must read that `*PSTR` is a `const char`, so `PSTR` is the address of a `const char`.

So if you type

```
typedef const char *PSTR,
                   *LPSTR,
                   OTHER;
```

`OTHER` and `*LPSTR` are `const char`s just as `*PSTR`.

Answer (score 0):

typedef is NOT alias..so if

```
typedef const char* PSTR, LPSTR;
```

PSTR is a pointer, LPSTR is a char

Comment: please remember * is a operator, not a type.

Comment: please remember * is a operator, not a type.  when you define char *x, means when you put *ahead of variable x, you get a char.

Answer (score 0):

Yup it's a `char`. The same rules for deducing the type of a variable in variable definitions apply in a typedef definition.